# Pass element IDs into an array for POST form process

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

So say I've got a series of images created with a php loop ->

```
<img src="http://..._1.jpg" class="profile-thumb" id="12345678">
<img src="http://..._2.jpg" class="profile-thumb" id="12345677">
<img src="http://..._3.jpg" class="profile-thumb" id="12345676">
```

The user can select the image elements by clicking on them jquery style a la ->

```
    $(".profile-thumb").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
```

So that when you click an image it adds an '.active' class to the image element ->

```
<img src="http://..._3.jpg" class="profile-thumb active" id="12345676">
```

How would I pass all the selected elements IDs into an array for use in a form process with PHP?

**User journey:**

Click photo -> Adds ID to array -> Click a submit button -> Uses POST array to perform a function with all IDs (e.g. send an email to all users using the IDs identified as active)

---

I want to pass the array to a loop with an AJAX call and echo output to the #post-info div ->

```
    $.get('post.php', function(data) {
        $('#post-info').html(data);
    });
```

How will I then read the POST array with a foreach loop?

---

**Solution:**

**HTML:**

```
<button id="share" class="off">
    <span>Sharer</span>
</button>
<div id="sharer">
<!-- Array will echo here -->
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    $("#share").click(function () {
        //Create var array
        var list = $('.active-profile').map(function(){return this.id;}).toArray();

        $.post('sharer.php', {ids:list}, function(data) {
            $('#sharer').html(data);
        });

    });
```

**PHP (sharer.php)**

```
        foreach ($_POST['ids'] as $id) {
            echo 'ID: ';
            echo $id;
        }
```

The javascript array (list) is sent via jquery POST and echo'd in the #sharer div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.profile-thumb.active').map(function(){return this.id}).toArray();
```

Also, instead of `if-hasClass-removeClass-else-addClass`, you can simply use:

```
$(".profile-thumb").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ErVbS/

Comment: Cheers for your help on this, I've edited the question for more info on reading the array.

Comment: @reekogi Use [`$.post('post.php', {ids:array_of_ids})`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) (`array_of_ids` as defined in my answer/fiddle. At the server's side, loop through the `$_POST['ids']` array.

Comment: I don't see you define 'ids:array_of_ids' in either, what are you referring to?

Comment: @reekogi The array is defined at the first line in my answer. In my fiddle, the array is called `list`.

Answer (score 0):

To sent an array of values to php you need to use a slightly different syntax. For each id you can create a url that looks something like.

```
http://test.com/?img_id[]=1&img_id[]=2&img_id[]=3
```

This will let you get the value `img_id` as an array in php.

```
$_POST['img_id'] // array of values. 
foreach ($_POST['img_id'] as $id) {
  print $id;
}  
// 1
// 2
// 3
```